# Example of an impractical algorithm known to be in P?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

It's generally accepted that problems that can be solved in polynomial time are "tractable" while algorithms requiring more time than this are intractable.  Of course, being solvable in polynomial time says nothing of absolute efficiency; for example, something that runs in time n<sup>1000</sup> is completely impractical in practice.

Although I've seen a fair number of polynomial-time algorithms, I've never seen one for a practical problem that ran in more than O(n<sup>4</sup>), which was the original version of Edmonds' matching algorithm.

My question is: **is there a well-known problem whose best polynomial-time algorithm is completely impractical for real inputs?** Obviously we can construct simple contrived problems that are utterly useless, but I'm curious if there's a famous problem for which the best known solution is both polynomial-time and entirely infeasible.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I should probably say that I'm looking for an algorithm with an enormous exponent on the problem size, rather than a hard-to-implement algorithm or one with a huge constant factor.  As Moron pointed out, there are many famous impractical algorithms with great asymptotic behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polynomial time algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100069/polynomial-time-algorithms)

Comment: I'm sure I've inadvertently written SQL statements with unindexed joins that had pretty crummy polynomial order. This is a well-known class of problem, although individual cases of it tend not to be published by their inventors ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PRIMES is in P: [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), complexity O(n<sup>6</sup>), where n = log N is the number of bits used to encode a prime candidate.

While this is a beautiful theoretical result, testing for primality is usually performed with [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test, or with other randomized algorithms alike.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the **Linear Programming Problem**. The well-known **simplex** algorithm is nonpolinomial, although there exists a polynomial(n^5, I think) algorithm which in pracrice runs much slower that the exponential one because of the very large coefficient

Answer (score 1):

There are too many problems:
[Ristricted bin packing problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V8M-48N546N-25&_user=10&_coverDate=06%2F30%2F1983&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1658664003&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=4ed835edc0fbf149f7eff0f9d0b80543&searchtype=a), for k (k is constant) different weight has algorithm of O(n^2k), so for k=3 is impractical (if bigger than n^4 is impractical).

Multiway k-Cut with given k (is P), sqrt(2) (frankly not in NP), ...

But  I think it's not important they are practical or impractical, in many cases they are restricted version of NP-Hard problems, and we can change this restricted version to some other instance with acceptance of some error to have a better algorithm (like what we doing in prime numbers, or what we doing with bin packing->restricted bin packing).